# In C++, CMailItem::Display(VARIANT &Modal) what is the VARIANT variable it is looking for?

Tags: c++, mfc, com, mailitem

I am writing a program that will pre-fill out an email to be send with data. However, I want to display the email to the user before actually sending it. The display method included in the MailItem class for C++ requires a VARIANT variable. I'm relatively new to C++, so I've never dealt with a VARIANT variable before. From my research, I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which explains what a Variant is.

When I declare a variant and use that for the parameter, I just get the error "Bad variable type." The code I used is below. I knew that wouldn't work, but I honestly don't know what to populate the variant with in order to get it to work. [The site for the MailItem class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861853.aspx) says that the variant variable shouldn't be required, but my code won't compile without it. That site appears to be for Visual Basic, which doesn't help me working in C++.

```
    VARIANT modal;
    olMailItem.Display(modal);
```

Do any of you have any experience with this and can point me in the right direction? I appreciate it.

Comment: This is not C++ code, it is VBA. VARIANT is also a VBA type.

Comment: Are `MailItem` and `CMailItem` the same thing? What is `CMailItem`?

Comment: The rest of the code works in C++ just fine. I can get it to populate and send, it just won't display. CMailItem is the name of the class as it is used in C++. I got it from [this code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2575036)

Comment: Please read the docs carefully (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687(v=vs.85).aspx) - it is not as straightforward. `VARIANT` requires to be initalized via `VariantInit` or you should use `variant_t` or `CComVariant` wrappers which take care of this.

Comment: I also wonder whether you're getting confused between the type `VARIANT` and the English word "variant".

Comment: Zdeslav Vojokiv, that variant_t wrapper did it!

Sorry to ask such simpleton questions, but you guys are awesome!

Comment: As you tagged this MFC, you might want to use the class `COleVariant`. This class provides several overloaded constructors to construct a variant from different types, like strings or ints.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's good to know. I'll note that for future reference!

Comment: You can't hope to grasp MFC and COM, at the same time, without knowing C++ or the Windows API. Good luck on your journey. You'll be wasting a lot of time unless you lay a solid foundation (Windows API, COM, C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, declare your variable to pass as something like this:

```
_variant_t modal(VARIANT_TRUE);// probably looking for a VARIANT_BOOL
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice guess! I’ve tested the answer in the reaction above and it is indeed correct! “_variant_t modal(VARIANT_TRUE);”

You can use this in combination with the working example I’ve used about: automate Outlook by using C++ in Visual Studio. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2575036

```
…
_variant_t modal(VARIANT_TRUE); 
yourCMailItem.Display(modal); // The e-mail appears
…
```